# Sort rows of a 2d array by a column of values in descending order

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am adding elements to multidimensional array like this

```
foreach($results as $res){
    $fwidth = $res[0];
    $fpath = $res[1];

    $sub = array(
        'img_w' => $fwidth,
        'img_path' => $fpath,
    );

    $widths[] = $sub;
}
```

And I want to sort $widths array by 'img_w' from bigger to smaller (DESC).

Comment: While reasonable clear, this question doesn't contain a [mcve] and therefore does not make a very attractive signpost for the canonical.  The answer is not adding any meaningful value to Stack Overflow.  I endorse the deletion of this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's [USort()](http://www.php.net/usort) function (user sort), which takes two arguments. The first is the array you want to sort. The second is a function that does the actual sorting (you write it yourself). The page I linked to has some examples that should cover your case.