# How do i sort the array Key items in php

Tags: php

```
foreach($sql_result['record2'] as $key ){
             echo  $key['ENO'];
}
```

when iam doing foreach loop  for the above statement .It outputs (10,9,2,8,4).I need it to sort to (2,4,8,9,10)
one more thing is "$key" is of Type Array.when i do like this array_multisort($key['ENO']). how do i acheive this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780157/sorting-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Is this an SQL resource object or a static array? The former could be done with SQL. Just curious as your variable names hint that this may be an SQL resource.

Comment: @Jason: It is SQL resource object

Comment: As others pointed out, you should sort the result of a query within the SQL itself, not within PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$vals = array();
foreach($sql_result['record2'] as $key ){
    $vals[] = $key['ENO']
}
sort($vals);
```

or if you want to pre-sort the values you could use `usort()`

Answer (score 0):

Untested Code, but something like the following should work....

```
$tmpArray = array();
foreach ($sql_result['record2'] as $key => $value) {
    array_push($tmpArray, $value['ENO']);
}

array_multisort($tmpArray, SORT_DESC);
```

At this point, `$tmpArray` will be your sorted array of values.  OR, you can just do an `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL, in which case the result set will be ordered by the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sort the array, you can simply append an "ORDER by ENO" to your SQL query to return an ordered result.